# mvc razor performance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, razor

Are there any differences between those examples in terms of performance

### First

Difference between this

```cs
@foreach (...)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(...)
}
```

and that

```cs
@foreach (...)
{
    Html.DisplayFor(...);
}
```

### Second

Difference between this

```cs
@{
    foreach (...)
    {
    }

    if(...)
    {
    }
}
```

and that

```cs
@foreach (...)
{
}

@if(...)
{
}
```

Comment: What did your own measurements tell you?

Comment: Doing your own research is actually a part of the sites etiquette http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice

Comment: I got my answer but couldn't avoid time wasting as I thought first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. In the first two examples, the @ is simply ignored. In the second example, it differs in that you have two code blocks instead of one. This does not measurably influence performance.